# Why are the inconsistencies between socket initialized in parent & socket used child via props?

Tags: javascript, react-native, socket.io

I have a client component that creates a socket.io connection. this happens in a parent component. from the parent component I can successfully emit AND receive an event back from the server across multiple clients. Once both clients are joined in a room, attempts to send & receive server events are buggy.

For instance: the first client tries to send a socket.io event from within a child component, using the socket within its props, which will be half successful, as in *only* the sending client receives the event back from the server, the other client receives nothing. this happens no matter what client tries to emit first, and it persists until second client tries to send. *then* both clients receive event back form server and everything works as expected from then on.

Further experimenting shows that if the `socket.on()` listener (for the event fired in the child component using the socket object stored in the child's props) is instead placed inside the parent component outside of the class, both clients receive the server event successfully as intended the first time.

I'm not sure if this is related to how props work/are updated. I tried comparing the value of `this.props.socket` with `prevProps.socket` in a didComponentUpdate function, but it was never called after client emitted an event.

parent component:

```
import stuff;
const socket = io("http://192.***.*.*:3000");
// socket.on("test", response => {
//   alert("response logged from parent component.");
// });
export default class Lobby extends React.component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }
  // first sending & receiving of server events that works properly
  join =() => {
    socket.emit("join");
    socket.on("matched", data => {
      this.setState({matched: true})
    }
  }
// conditional rendering of child component based on this.state.matched
render() {
  return this.state.matched == false ? (
    <View> <Text> Not matched </Text> </View> 
    ):(
    <ChildComponent
      socket={socket}/> );
}
}
```

Child component:

```
import stuff;
export default class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }
  onTest = () => {
    alert("outgoing test alert");
    this.props.socket.emit("test");
    this.props.socket.on("test", () => {alert("incoming test alert")});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.onTest}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I expect both clients to receive the event from the server the first attempt. however, if client 1 or client 2 makes first attempt, only that client receives the server event, respectively. but after that half-failed attempt, if the *other* client makes an attempt, both clients receive from server.

Comment: This seems a strange way to implement sockets. Normally you give each client their _own_ socket connection, you don't make them share sockets (because that's just asking for conflicts in `on(...)` handling). E.g. `this.socket = io(this.props.socketURL);` in the child component constructor, so you know that the calls are isolated appropriately.

Comment: each client creates its own socket. the parent component is where this happens, in every client that is emulated

Comment: not in the code you're showing: you create one socket (and you don't even create it in the Lobby constructor, so that's another thing you probably want to do) and then you pass that down into each child, so they're all sharing the exact same socket.

Comment: each *client* creates its own socket, with this code. this can be demonstrated. run multiple iOS simulators and alert the socket.id.

Comment: for example, im logging the socket id in the server console (which is unique as defined by socket.io). each time a new client connects, its logged, and verifiable that its not the same socket. im not sure why you're suggesting its the same connection

Comment: because _the code you show_ has a single `socket` being defined, and everything (the Lobby and all children) share that same socket. So if that's not actually what you're doing: you might need to show more, or show different, code.